# Facebook application - The server refused the connection

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, ssl

I have an app on facebook it has SSL certificates there are no mixed contents everything is on SSL. my problem is on first try, the page will show a "The server refused the connection" error. but when refreshing the page, it will show the SSL content.

How do I fix the "The server refused the connection". coz, I'm losing app users because they don't refresh. when they see the error, they exit right away. 
I tried header refresh to no avail. Tried it on PHP also in Javascript. but if you access the app directly on its https page, it shows fine. no need to refresh. 
canvas page: https://apps.facebook.com/ulinksms/

Comment: do you mean it shows the error only when opened with non-https link i.e. http://apps.facebook.com/ulinksms/ ?

Comment: nop. the error persist even when the link is https

Comment: added info: I already did an SSL check to verify that I don't have mixed content.